# Sort table, using loop in MySQL with SELECT and UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sorting, select, loops

Please help me to sort my table in MySQL. I need to make it only once, not for use in scripts or somewhere else dynamically.

Here's my table 'page':

```
|  ...  |  title  |  ...  |  parent_id  |  ...  |  position  |  ...  |
```

I need to update table with the rule: select all rows with the same `parent_id`, sort them by `title` DESC and set first row `position` = 0, second = 1 etc. And loop this for all `parent_id`.

I made a query to display what I need, but with no UPDATE and only for one `parent_id`. But as there are some thousands `parent_id` this query needs a loop. And after selecting, `position` must be updated to have the same value as @number for current row.

```
SET @number = -1;
SELECT @number:=@number+1 AS number, p.* FROM `page` AS p WHERE parent_id=1
  ORDER BY title DESC;
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT @p:=0, @parent:=0;
UPDATE page p1
JOIN
( SELECT title, 
  CASE WHEN @parent<>parent_id THEN @p:=0 ELSE @p:=@p+1 END as position,
  @parent:=parent_id as parent_id
  FROM page
  ORDER BY parent_id, title DESC ) p2
ON p1.title = p2.title AND p1.parent_id = p2.parent_id
SET p1.position = p2.position
```

If your (parent_id,title) pairs aren't unique use your primary key as join condition - you will need to add it to select in parenthesis.

Comment: piotrm, can you please help upgrading this code [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23031633/sort-table-using-loop-in-mysql-with-select-and-update-with-natural-order)? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pure MySQL loop you'll have to create a stored procedure to do your looping. You should read up on [MySQL cursors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html) and then implement something like this:

```
DECLARE current_number INT;
DECLARE current_parent INT;
DECLARE current_id INT;
DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT p.id FROM `page` AS p WHERE parent_id=current_parent;
SET current_parent := 1;
SET current_number := -1;
OPEN my_cursor;
read_loop: LOOP
    SET current_number := current_number + 1;
    FETCH my_cursor INTO current_id;
    UPDATE page SET position = current_number WHERE id = current_id;
    #whatever other logic you have
    SET current_parent := current_id;
END LOOP;
CLOSE my_cursor;
```

Obviously I'm making lots of assumptions about your logic, but hopefully this will get your thought process moving ahead.