# Sort table, using loop in MySQL with SELECT and UPDATE with NATURAL ORDER

Tags: mysql, sorting, loops, select, natural-sort

Some long time ago I asked [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143325/sort-table-using-loop-in-mysql-with-select-and-update) to help with sorting the table. And user "piotrm" gave an exellent sollution, thanks to him! It works perfect!

```
SELECT @p:=0, @parent:=0;
UPDATE page p1
JOIN
( SELECT title, 
  CASE WHEN @parent<>parent_id THEN @p:=0 ELSE @p:=@p+1 END as position,
  @parent:=parent_id as parent_id
  FROM page
  ORDER BY parent_id, title DESC ) p2
ON p1.title = p2.title AND p1.parent_id = p2.parent_id
SET p1.position = p2.position
```

Now I need this code to be upgraded with NATURAL SORTING. I mean it STILL needs to be sorted THE SAME WAY, but when it meets TITLE STARTING WITH '2', '13', '1', '26', it has to be ordered NOT '1', '13', '2', '26'; BUT '1', '2', '13', '26'.

I apologize for lack of knowledge in SQL, but I really need your help! Thank you a lot!

Comment: [piotrm](http://stackoverflow.com/users/722232/piotrm), can you, please, help with it? I'm really stuck with this =(

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @p:=0, @parent:=0;
UPDATE page p1
JOIN
( SELECT title, 
  CASE WHEN @parent<>parent_id THEN @p:=0 ELSE @p:=@p+1 END as position,
  @parent:=parent_id as parent_id
  FROM page
  ORDER BY LENGTH(title), title, parent_id ASC ) p2
ON p1.title = p2.title AND p1.parent_id = p2.parent_id
SET p1.position = p2.position
```

Comment: No, it works when titles are ONLY numbers, but they JUST START with numbers. And, btw, it doesn't work with those titles that are composed only with letters. But I need the code to work with BOTH situations. Any way, thanks)

Comment: Ok. Try this `ORDER BY CAST(title AS UNSIGNED)` instead of LENGTH

Comment: still no =( 1.Randomized mess with letter titles 2. Those with digits at the beginning almost normal, but '16...' - '19...' somehow are not on the place they suppoes to be 3. It works only ASC

Comment: you need to create new table/column with sorting modifier with relation to id and next join this table in select and order by it

Comment: i'm sure there must be a simplier way.. if no one suggests, I will try this one. =)